# Make tableView readonly but scrollable

Tags: swift

How can i easily make a tableview readonly but scrollable?

i tried to set tableView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false.

However, it disabled the scrolling action either.

Comment: Try using a [UIScrollView](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiscrollview)

Comment: Define "tableview readonly".

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I understand your question but a table view has no default interaction on it unless you write it.
You create the table view, configure the data source and the cells and thats it.
You can add behavior to it so when you tap on a cell allows you to navigate to detail, delete it, etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want the cells to react visually when the user taps them, just set the [selectionStyle](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewcellselectionstyle) of the `UITableViewCell`s to `UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone`